# How to log in back to the same page when a session expires using 'devise'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

A user is logged in, and his session expires. So now what I want is, when the user logs in again, he should be redirected to same page he was on before the session expired. If I try to set a session variable with the location of the last page, then again the session gets destroyed when it expires.

I followed *[How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out)* in device's documentation.

Comment: Why are you clearing the session when logging in? Devise doesn't do that. Also Devise have a function to do this for you, actually it's the default behaviour!

Comment: Using the `request.refferer` method doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  before_action :authenticate_user!

    private
    def storable_location?
          request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? 
        end

    def store_user_location!
      # :user is the scope we are authenticating
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end
end
```

And then to redirect after signing in, you have to override this method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sessions? Pff, try using cookies, update the page [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) on every page to the cookie, and therefore when they leave, it will come back to the last viewed page, and the cookie will stay. However, I can't give an example, I don't even know what Ruby is? Hopefully cookies exist there too.

I can give you the basic logic, OK?

Users visits page:

```
A: URL = www.abc.com/A
B: URL = www.abc.com/B
```

However when they load A, it sets a cookie to the URL, `/A`. When they go to B it 
sets URL B. They left... Then when they come back, it will still be set to B, and you can use that to redirect them to B's URL.

Comment: Sessions are temporary until a browser closes... cookies expire when you tell them to, it could be hours, days, years or centuries before it expires.... thats the difference

Comment: If you don't know, Ruby, Rails or Devise then don't answer... This doesn't solve the real problem.